# ext-js chart, multiple series on same chart

Tags: extjs, charts

Ext-js Chart,
I have a line graph, and I wish to add a single line(eg. average line) to the graph. 
The only way I can think of to emulate this line is to do the following:
add an extra field with identical value to all my data points if, but this seems to be a waste and plus I don't want to show the dots that comes with the line.

is there anyway to add an average line to my existing chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [Ext-JS-Charts-Creating-line-charts-without-markers](http://www.miamicoder.com/post/2010/03/15/Ext-JS-Charts-Creating-line-charts-without-markers.aspx)